# Xpath - joining text within hrefs

Tags: xpath

```
<ul><li>
<a href="/example" class="my class">A name of something</a>
by <a href="/url-example">Hello World</a> and <a href="/url-example">Goodbye for now</a>  (1975)
</li></ul>
```

I cannot seem to grab the text from this loop so it returns me:

"Hello World and Goodbye for now"

How do I make xpath grab these bits of text and put them together? I tried concat and also using a pipe between the two queries:

```
/ul/li/a[2]|/ul/li/a[3]
concat(/ul/li/a[2]|/ul/li/a[3])
```

But this doesn't seem to provide me with the text I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `HelloWorld` using `/ul/li/a[2]` since it is the contents of the second `a`.

`Goodbye for now` is at `/ul/li/a[3]`

Now `and` in not in an `a` element, but in the `li`. It's the third text node (the first one is a line-break, the second one is line-break + `by`). You can retrieve it with `/ul/li/text()[3]`.

To obtain the sentence you want you can use a simple `concat`:

```
concat(/ul/li/a[2],/ul/li/text()[3],/ul/li/a[3])
```